# JS: Replace whitespace with character

Tags: javascript, regex, str-replace

I'm trying to figure out how to replace all the whitespaces with a character given. 
My code is duplicating the character when the whitespace is replaced.

This is the exercise, and my code so far:

This function receives a string. It also takes an optional character, which should default to an underscore ('_') when not given.

It should return the same string, but with all groups of whitespace (spaces, tabs and line breaks) replaced by a single instance of the character in the second argument.

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {
  return str.replace(/\s/g, character);
}
```

Also, I don't know how to default the underscore. Could anyone give me a hand, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: *"Also, I don't know how to default the underscore"* Best to ask **one** question/question, and also be sure to [search thoroughly](/help/searching) as the topic of how to default parameter values is very well-covered on SO (and elsewhere).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/\s/g` matches **one** character of whitespace (repeatedly). To match one *or more* characters of whitespace in a row, use `+` after `\s`: `/\s+/g`.

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, character);
}
```

> Also, I don't know how to default the underscore

Before ES2015, you'd do something like this:

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {
  character = character || "_";
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, character);
}
```

...because `character` will be `undefined` if not given, which is falsy. Or if you want to allow for `""` (which is also falsy), then:

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {
  character = typeof character === "undefined" ? "_" : character;
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, character);
}
```

As of ES2015, you can use a default parameter value:

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character = "_") {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, character);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To include multiple white spaces you should add `+` like:`/\s+/g`

So your code should be:

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, character);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression `one or more` matches. So `/\s+/` means white spaces least one max any. Then I am checking whether `character` is defined or not with ternary operator. If it is not then i am assigning `_`.

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, character?character: '_');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defaulting to '_', insert :

```
var chr = (typeof chr !== 'undefined') ? chr : '_';
```

Replacing groups of white spaces with one or more elements in the group (but not zero) :

```
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, chr);
```

So we end up with :

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, chr) {
  var chr = (typeof chr !== 'undefined') ? chr : '_';
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, chr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend the string object with the method:

```
String.prototype.replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter = function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter(theCharacter) 
{
    if ((typeof theCharacter !== 'string') || (theCharacter === ''))
    {
        theCharacter = '_';
    }
    return this.replace(/\s+/g, theCharacter);
}
```

My checkings for the character based on typeof for string or if theCharacter is a empty string

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "this is  a\ttest\n2";
var str2 = str.replace(/\s+/g,'_');

console.log(str2);
```

this is replace all white spaces with a single underscore.

Answer (score -2):

This is my final solution. Thanks for your help.

```
function replaceWhitespaceWithCharacter (str, character) {

       if(character){
        return str.replace(/\s+/g, character);
       }else{
         return str.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
       }
    }
```